# Delete files from a ZIP archive without Decompressing in Java or maybe Python

Tags: java, python, zip

Delete files from a ZIP archive without decompressing using Java (Preferred) or Python

Hi,

I work with large ZIP files containing many hundreds of highly compressed text files. When I decompress the ZIP file it can take a while and easily consume up to 20 GB of diskspace. I would like to remove certain files from these ZIP files without having to decompress and recompress only the files I want.

Of course it is certainly possible to do this the long way, but very inefficient.

I would prefer to do this in Java, but will consider Python

Comment: Step 1:  Read this.  http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html  Step 2: Post the code you tried.

Comment: @S.Lott: That won't work without decompressing the file first.

Comment: ZIP is not designed for fast updates and involves rewriting the whole file even for simple changes.  Instead of deleting these references I suggest you maintain a file which lists the deleted files, and another ZIP or directory for the altered files (if you need that)  An over night/off line process can rewrite the file to reflect all the changes.

Comment: @Gabe: I'm unclear on what "That won't work" means.  Could you explain?  It seemed like a little reading would help clarify the question.

Comment: @S.Lott, sure, it's possible to read the directory structure of the zip w/o full decompress. It's also possible to remove entries from the zip w/o fully rebuilding it, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: @bestsss: First, how would one do that?  The Python libraries don't support it.  Second, why would it not be recommended?  Perhaps you should provide a proper answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: @S.Lott, dunno about python, java can't naturally do it either, but the code is relatively trivial. Surprisingly wikepedia has an ok article on the zip format, i guess everyone can figure how to do it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29, the main issue would be that the file will grow fragmented (and bigger) after deletion,

Comment: @bestsss: Perhaps you should provide a proper answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: @S.Lott: Sorry for not being more clear, but my baby started to cry just as I started typing. What I meant was that using the Python zipfile lib means decompressing/recompressing all the files. There's no delete operation nor any way to get the raw compressed data.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - you wrote, *ZIP is not designed for fast updates and involves rewriting the whole file even for simple changes*.  This isn't true. DotNetZip can do what is requested in this post - using that library, you can remove entries from a zipfile, or add entries to a zipfile, without decompressing and re-compressing unnecessarily. The format itself does not prevent what is requested here.  It's just a matter of having the appropriate intelligence in the zip library.

Comment: @Cheeso, To remove a file it has to rewrite from that point in the ZIP as a minimum, even if it avoids compressing/decompressing. For a 20 GB file ZIP that would take a long time. AFAIK, removing an entry does not mean you have to decompress/re-compress other files in any case.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. Just a point - the zip files are not 20GB they decompress to 20GB. They are usually around 1GB of actual zip file.

Comment: @Lawrey, the expensive thing is typically the compression, and in some cases encryption. Disk I/O is not the thing that will take "a long time".

Comment: @bestsss, there is a natural solution in [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36088523/3142238)

Answer (score 6):

[I've found this on web](http://thinktibits.blogspot.hk/2013/02/Delete-Files-From-ZIP-Archive-Java-Example.html)

clean solution with only standard library, but I'm not sure whether it's included in android sdk, to be found.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
public class ZPFSDelete {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        /* Define ZIP File System Properies in HashMap */    
        Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>(); 
        /* We want to read an existing ZIP File, so we set this to False */
        zip_properties.put("create", "false"); 

        /* Specify the path to the ZIP File that you want to read as a File System */
        URI zip_disk = URI.create("jar:file:/my_zip_file.zip");

        /* Create ZIP file System */
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) {
            /* Get the Path inside ZIP File to delete the ZIP Entry */
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("source.sql");
            System.out.println("About to delete an entry from ZIP File" + pathInZipfile.toUri() ); 
            /* Execute Delete */
            Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
            System.out.println("File successfully deleted");   
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything runs without a problem, but when I loop over my entries again afterwards, I can still see my file in the list.

Comment: it should be running successfully because I used it on my apps and it worked perfectly. I might have an explanation to your situation, that your entry object is out dated, I mean like you retrieve it before the deletion and it does not refresh

Answer (score 2):

I don't have code to do this, but the basic idea is simple and should translate into almost any language the same way. The ZIP file layout is just a series of blocks that represent files (a header followed by the compressed data), finished off with a central directory that just contains all the metadata. Here's the process:

1. Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you want to delete.
2. Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you *don't* want to delete **or** you hit the central directory.
3. Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you want to delete **or** you hit the central directory.
4. Copy all the data you found in step 3 back onto the data you skipped in step 2 until you find another file you want to delete **or** you hit the central directory.
5. Go to step 2 unless you've hit the central directory.
6. Copy the central directory to where ever you left off copying, leaving out the entries for the deleted files and changing the offsets to reflect how much you moved each file.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29 for all the details on the ZIP file structures.

As bestsss suggests, you might want to perform the copying into another file, so as to prevent losing data in the event of a failure.

Comment: if you do that you'd most likely need a temp file (to prevent fail/error during compact).So the process will be reconstructing the file w/o the unneeded (and very slow) decompress/compress.

Comment: just a side note - this isn't an answer because the OP asked about Java or Python, but...The DotNetZip library does this, more or less transparently for .NET apps. When you read a zip file, you get a collection of entries. Call `.Remove()` on some of the entries, then call `.Save()` on the zipfile, and the library runs through a series of steps that is pretty close to what is described here, writing only the entries that have not been marked for deletion. When updating an existing zip file using DotNetZip, there's no unnecessary decompression and recompression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible for JAVA using library called **TRUEZIP**.

> TrueZIP is a Java based virtual file system (VFS) which enables client
> applications to perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations
> on archive files as if they were virtual directories, even with nested
> archive files in multithreaded environments

see below link for more information
https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/

Answer (score 0):

Ok think I found a potential solution from www.javaer.org. It definitely deletes files inside the zip and I don't think it is decompressing anything. Here is the code:

```
public static void deleteZipEntry(File zipFile,
     String[] files) throws IOException {
       // get a temp file
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
       // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
tempFile.delete();
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
boolean renameOk=zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
if (!renameOk)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("could not rename the file "+zipFile.getAbsolutePath()+" to "+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
while (entry != null) {
    String name = entry.getName();
    boolean toBeDeleted = false;
    for (String f : files) {
        if (f.equals(name)) {
            toBeDeleted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!toBeDeleted) {
        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
        // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
        int len;
        while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
            zout.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
    entry = zin.getNextEntry();
}
// Close the streams        
zin.close();
// Compress the files
// Complete the ZIP file
zout.close();
tempFile.delete();
```

}

Comment: ZipOutputStream  recreates the file and so it does decompress EVERYTHING and COMPRESSes it back. I wonder if you understand anything about the code, the temp file is visible from miles ahead. reading only 1024bytes per pass would be especially ineffective too.

Comment: Right - the code above, that calls `zin.read` and `zout.write`, does decompression and compression, respectively. You could do what you want, with not very much effort, by writing some logic that reads directly form the filestream and writes to the filestream. You need to avoid the read and write on ZipInputStream and ZipOutputStream. The answer from Gabe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244963/delete-files-from-a-zip-archive-without-decompressing-in-java-or-maybe-python/5249145#5249145) captures the idea.