# Java: Deleting directories with contents from Zip/Jar file

Tags: java, zip

I'm completely new at working with Zip files in Java. Basically, I have to delete a directory inside a Jar file (Zip format) with all contents. How would I go ahead and do that? I tried searching google for quite some time, but can't seem to find an example or guide that's easy to follow. As I'm new to the subject, I need code to learn from.

Also, it is important that I must not decompress and compress the Jar, as it contains over 1700 files, and the process of extracting/compressing everything would take some time.

Here's the directory structure:

```
MyJarFile.jar
├─ <DIR> assets
├─ <DIR> net
├─ <DIR> META-INF
│  ├─ MANIFEST.MF
│  ├─ MOJANGCS.RSA
│  └─ MOJANGCS.SF
├─ File1
├─ File2
├─ ...
```

I need to delete META-INF from the Jar file, and the contents within it, but I'm not sure how to do it, and where to start. Any help on this one?

Sincerely,
- bilde2910

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244963/delete-files-from-a-zip-archive-without-decompressing-in-java-or-maybe-python

Comment: @MarkElliot I found it, but I also need to find a solution that doesn't unzip the file first. There are over 1700 files in the Jar, so it would take a lot of time. I mean, it can be done in all other programming languages, so I bet there has to be a way.

Comment: The top-voted answer in the linked question provides a method for doing this without unzipping, why is that not sufficient for you?

Comment: @MarkElliot As I've hardly worked with Zips before, I could have used an example. I learn better from examples, especially when the post you mentioned has a rather complex procedure.

Comment: In particular, your question claims that you "tried searching google for quite some time, but can't seem to find a solution, guide or example". The top-voted answer is everything but an example; the second response provides some example code for interacting with zip files. You could've greatly refined your question by indicating you'd found this solution, but are struggling to implement...and with what specifically you're struggling with.

Comment: @MarkElliot Okay, I'll admin I worded myself a little wrong. The top voted answer has a guide, however, it is too complicated for me to be able to follow. The second answer has code, however, it requires extracting the Zip file ("ZipOutputStream recreates the file and so it does decompress EVERYTHING and COMPRESSes it back."). The third answer doesn't even have anything to do with Zip interaction. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: I did't try that but what about Apache Compress tool? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/. My colleague used it for similar purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure to delete a file within a jar:

```
magallanes:prueba_extraer_jar coti$ jar tf EjemploDebugger.jar 
META-INF/INDEX.LIST
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ejemplodebugger/
ejemplodebugger/CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.class
ejemplodebugger/EjemploDebugger.class
src/ejemplodebugger/CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.java
src/ejemplodebugger/EjemploDebugger.java
magallanes:prueba_extraer_jar coti$ zip -d EjemploDebugger.jar src/ejemplodebugger/CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.java
deleting: src/ejemplodebugger/CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.java
magallanes:prueba_extraer_jar coti$ jar tf EjemploDebugger.jar 
META-INF/INDEX.LIST
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ejemplodebugger/
ejemplodebugger/CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.class
ejemplodebugger/EjemploDebugger.class
src/ejemplodebugger/EjemploDebugger.java
magallanes:prueba_extraer_jar coti$
```

This shows the code I used in order to remove one Java file from a previously-created jar. Since the deleted file (CalculadorDeNumerosPrimos.java) resides within src/ejemplodebugger I had to prepend the path. Once the file has been removed, I show again the contents of the jar in order to be able to check.