# Deleting file inside a zip in java

Tags: java, zip4j

I have a folder which contains some files, now I want to append these files to a zip which already exists. If the file I am adding to the zip is already there, then I am replacing the old file with the new one. For zip operations I am using zip4j jar. This is the piece of my code

```
        for(File entry : temp.listFiles())
        {
            String file = entry.getName();

            if(trgZip.getFileHeader(file) != null)
            {
                trgZip.removeFile(file);
            }
            ZipParameters param = new ZipParameters();
            trgZip.addFile(entry, param);
        }
```

But I am getting this exception 
**net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: cannot delete old zip file**
can anyone please suggest what should I do to correct this, or where I am going wrong, or how does this **removeFile** method works, so that I can try locate the point of error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files from a ZIP archive without Decompressing in Java or maybe Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244963/delete-files-from-a-zip-archive-without-decompressing-in-java-or-maybe-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... !! Provide path to you zip file as first argument and filename which you want to delete from zip file as your second argument.

```
public static void deleteFile(String zipFilePath,String fileName) throws Exception{
        Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>(); 
        zip_properties.put("create", "false"); 

        /* Specify the path to the ZIP File that you want to read as a File System */
        URI zip_disk = URI.create("jar:file:"+zipFilePath);

        /* Create ZIP file System */
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) {
            /* Get the Path inside ZIP File to delete the ZIP Entry */
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath(fileName);
            System.out.println("About to delete an entry from ZIP File" + pathInZipfile.toUri() ); 
            /* Execute Delete */
            Files.delete(pathInZipfile);
            System.out.println("File successfully deleted");   
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I have tried using FileSystems, but I was not being able to make it work. It kept on sending the error, **ReadOnlyFileSystems** Exception. Can suggest anything with zip4j, or how to make this FilesSystem thing work.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace and the code you have tried.

Comment: Use **java.nio.file.FileSystem** not FilesSystem or FileSystems